# How to update dictionary and its list contents?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've created two dictionaries that I wish to combine like this:

```
dict1 = {'temp1':[1,2,3,4]}
dict2 = {'temp1': [3,4,5],'temp2':[15,16,17]}
dict1.update(dict2)
```

I was hoping to get this:

```
dict1 = {'temp1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'temp2': [15, 16, 17]}
```

But instead I get this:

```
dict1 = {'temp1': [3, 4, 5], 'temp2': [15, 16, 17]}
```

How do I update and filter out duplicates in the lists in the dictionary?

Comment: I don't know of a hacky way to do this, you'll have to loop through each and set a if condition. If in dict then update otherways update (append)...

Comment: Do you care about the order of the inner values? It would be nice to just use sets instead of lists.

Answer (score 2):

`dict.update` *replaces* the values under existing keys, which explains the result you're getting (your values are lists of integers, but the `update` method isn't aware of that, and wouldn't know how to merge the data anyway)

Here, you've created a specialized dictionary, with values being list of integers.

What you want is a *custom merge* function.

I would rebuild a third dict using dict comprehension on the union of the keys, and merging the lists as a set (for unicity) then turn back to list:

```
dict1 = {'temp1':[1,2,3]}
dict2 = {'temp1': [3,4,5],'temp2':[15,16,17]}

dict3 = {k:list(set(dict1.get(k,[])+dict2.get(k,[]))) for k in set(dict2) | set(dict1)}

print(dict3)
```

result:

```
{'temp2': [16, 17, 15], 'temp1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

The magic of `dict1.get(k,[])` is that if the key isn't present, it returns an empty list so `+` works and the expression isn't too complex.

the order of the elements isn't guaranteed because of the use of a `set` at some point. You could use `sorted(set ...)` instead of simple conversion to `list` to guarantee that the integer values are sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a subclass of `dict` that updates lists the way you want:

```
from collections import UserDict

class ListDict(UserDict):
    def __init__(self, data_as_dict):
        self.data = data_as_dict

    def update(self, other):
        for key, sublist in other.items():
            self.data[key] = list(set(self.data.get(key, [])) | set(sublist))

dict1 = {'temp1':[1,2,3]}
dict2 = {'temp1': [3,4,5],'temp2':[15,16,17]}

d = ListDict(dict1)
d.update(dict2)
print(d)

# {'temp1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'temp2': [16, 17, 15]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your dict contains list, we could do something like this-

```
dict1 = {'temp1':[1,2,3]}
dict2 = {'temp1': [3,4,5],'temp2':[15,16,17]}
for k, v in dict1.iteritems():
    try:
        dict2[k] = list(set(dict2[k]+v))
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Obviously this method is **hacky** but solves the problem. You should probably see [Jean's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51352141/6104077) answer as this answer is how something **can** be done but there always are better ways to doing it

Comment: this doesn't filter out the duplicates. And this is python 2 only because of iteritems(). Also this method isn't symmetric: if there are more keys in dict1 than in dict2 it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, did not see the duplicate part, let me edit that

Answer (score 0):

May not be the most efficient way but one way may be as following:

- Iterate over key for one of the dictionary and check if same key exist in other dictionary.
- If it exist then, update values that do not exist (*you can use set for this purpose or loop values*).
- If it does not exist then, add key and copy values to the dictionary.

---

```
dict1 = {'temp1':[1,2,3,4]}
dict2 = {'temp1': [3,4,5],'temp2':[15,16,17]}


for key in dict2: # check over keys in dict2
    if key in dict1: # if key also exist in dict1 then update values
        for v in dict2[key]:
            if v not in dict1[key]:  # update values only if does not exist
                dict1[key].append(v)
    else: # if key does not exist copy the values from dict2 for the key
        dict1[key] = dict2[key][:]

# dict1 is {'temp2': [15, 16, 17], 'temp1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If they can't repeat why not use sets from the start?

```
dict1 = {'temp1': {1,2,3,4}}
dict2 = {'temp1': {3,4,5},'temp2':{15,16,17}}

for k,v in dict2.items():
    dict1[k] = v.union(dict1.get(k,{}))

print(dict1)
```

Returns:

```
{'temp1': {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 'temp2': {15, 16, 17}}
```